# How to create a score counter where scores add for every second?

Tags: python, pygame

I'd like to add special score counter to my game can finish when Player get, for example 1000 scores, and Player will win, however, I absolutely don't know how to realize it. What do I have to do? Probably, I have to use `pygame.USEREVENT + 1`;

```
import time
total_score = 1000
scores = 0
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        #[...]
        self.score = scores
        self.plus = 1

    def update(self):
        #[...]
        self.score += self.plus
def game():
    global health 
    Game = True
    while Game:
        #[...]
        print_text('Total score  ' + str(scores), 725, 25)
```

Comment: So, what do you need exactly? A counter that gets updated adding 1 each second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a timer event. In pygame exists a timer event. Use [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to repeatedly create a [`USEREVENT`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) in the event queue. The time has to be set in milliseconds. e.g.:

```py
timer_interval = 1000 # 1 seconds
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, timer_interval)
```

Each timer event needs a unique id. The ids for the user events have to be between `pygame.USEREVENT` (24) and `pygame.NUMEVENTS` (32). In this case `pygame.USEREVENT+1` is the event id for the timer event.

Increment the score when the timer event occurs:

```py
running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

         elif event.type == timer_event:
             player.score += player.plus
```

Comment: I know that I won't speak according to the rules, however, I express gratitude for you helped me again and again. I respect and appreciate you!

Comment: @Vildan Thank you. You're welcome. ("Thank you" comments are also against the rules - no matter, someone will delete them)